Prime ideal and localisation
My lecture notes states:
Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a commutative ring with identity. Suppose $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{O}$ is a prime ideal. The localisation $\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{p}$ is the set of equivalence classes of fractions $\frac{x}{y}, y\notin \mathfrak{p}, \frac{x}{y}=\frac{x_1}{y_1} \Leftrightarrow \exists u \notin \mathfrak{p} : u(xy_1 - x_1y)=0$. Since the ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime this set is a ring.
My questions are:

Why do we need $u$? I understand that if $\mathcal{O}$ is an integral domain then we don't need it, but I do not understand its role in non integral domain. May be there is an example?
Why the fact that $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime implies that the set is a ring?


Prime ideals are subsets of rings, not members.

The relation won't be transitive without the $u$. This question is similar to: Why is $s''$ needed in $s''(rs'-r's)=0$ for equivalence of fractions in localizations. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is a lot elided here - the definition of addition and multiplication, for example, in the localization. Then you have to use the same arguments you use in the fact that the field of fractions of an integral domain (which is really the localization of the zero ideal, since the zero ideal is prime in an integral domain.)

But the reason you you need $\mathfrak p$ prime is that the product and sum of two fractions gives a denominator $y_1y_2.$ where $y_1,y_2\notin\mathfrak p$ are the den9minator of the fractions. But if $\mathfrak p$ is not prime,  it is possible that $y_1y_2\in\mathfrak p.$

There is a generalization of localization: Given $S\subset\mathcal O,$ with $0\notin S$ and $S$ is closed under multiplication. Then the localization relative to $S,$ sometimes written $S^{-1}\mathcal O,$  where we allow only the elements of $S$ in the denominator. In the ideal case, $S=\mathcal O\setminus \mathfrak p$ is closed under multiplication iff $\mathfrak p$ is prime.

Thank you, Thomas and Viktor!
